# Unable to submit Spark job to yarn cluster using Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to submit spark job through SparkSubmit class on a Scala application from my local Windows machine to a remote Yarn cluster, but the spark ResourceManager always try to connect to 0.0.0.0.

```
val args = Array(
  "--master", "yarn",
  "--verbose",
  "--class",  "application-class",
  "--num-executors", "1",
  "--executor-cores", "1",
  "--executor-memory", "10g",
  "--deploy-mode", "cluster",
  "--driver-memory", "10g",
  "path-to-jar", "1")

SparkSubmit.main(args)
```

Below is the error

```
Failed to connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032: retries get failed due to exceeded maximum allowed retries number: 10
```

When I try to submit the spark job through Command Prompt/Windows shell with same arguments as with Scala, then it works fine and submits the job to the cluster.

I have already `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and `YARN_CONF_DIR` in environment variables and my `yarn-site.xml` has `yarn.resourcemanager.address` defined with remote IP.

Am I missing anything here?